# Do bookmarks inside a document help search engines indexing content?

Tags: url, search-engine-indexing

Say someone implements a FAQ page and decides to use bookmarks in their page, for example:

```
<a id="Question2"></a><h2>My faq question 2?</h2>
```

Does it help search engines indexing content in such pages? Do they use bookmark URLs such as:

```
http://mysite.com/mypage.html#MyBookmark
```

Is it worth the SEO effort?

Comment: Do you mean `<a href="#Question2"></a><h2 id="Question2">My faq question 2?</h2>` as your markup won't work unless your using some kind of JavaScript trigger.

Comment: In HTML 5, my understanding is that <a name="bookmark"></a> has been replaced by <a id="bookmark"></a>. But, are you saying one can use an URL followed by # and a header id (in other words, skip <a name="...">)?

Comment: Yes Google Named Anchors which returns: [Typepad Knowledge Base: Named Anchors](http://help.typepad.com/anchor-tags.html).  This may look old, but it will always work.

Comment: Name was replaced with ID but this doesn't mean you need to use an ID within an anchor.

Comment: See > http://jsfiddle.net/ku21nmvv/ Unless I'm mistaken what your attempting to do. Using a id without a HREF would mean the link can't be copied using right click copy or do anything when clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's be clear on something. Your example:

```
<a id="Question2"></a><h2>My faq question 2?</h2>
```

...may be better served as...

```
<a id="Question2"><h2>My faq question 2?</h2></a>
```

...your decision of course. Both are fine.

To answer your question. Yes- but only slightly. Your link is not to an external (from the page) resource so it may be discounted at least somewhat, however, the link text carries some weight as well as the header tag in giving a clue as to what your topic is about. Nothing more. From my experience, I would us it if it makes sense for the site users but not to influence Google. The effect would be too small since Google is at least hip to the tricks and this was a black-hat trick years ago when the influence was greater. It still makes sense and is a legal construct so you will not get penalized unless you abuse it.

*ALWAYS(!)* develop for humans and not for machines. This is not advice taken out of thin air. Google, in particular, is looking for sites that expressly fit this paradigm and rewarding them handsomely. It has been a deliberate shift in their strategy.